# Java SWT: Displaying image Pixel by Pixel but Blues look Yellow

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bitmap, swt

I am displaying an image Pixel by Pixel.  All the blues look yellow.  I suspect the issue is with the PalletteData or with the following line(The Pixel object just holds the int representation of the colour):

```
p = (pixel.Alpha<<24) | (pixel.Red<<16) | (pixel.Green<<8) | pixel.Blue;
```

Note: as the call is from Java to C++ accross JNI, there are some conversions:

Each colour is read in to an unsigned char. Then it is converted to char to pass accross JNI. Then is read as a byte on the Java side. Then converted to Int

Here is the full listing. Can you see what my problem is?

```
            PaletteData palette=new PaletteData(0xff0000,0x00ff00,0xff);
            ImageData imageData = new ImageData(width, height,32,palette);

            int pixelVecLoc=0;
            for (int h = 0; h<1300; h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w<1300; w++)
                {
                    int p = 0;
                    Pixel pixel = pixelVec.get(pixelVecLoc);
                    p = (pixel.Alpha<<24) | (pixel.Red<<16) | (pixel.Green<<8) | pixel.Blue;                        

                    imageData.setPixel(w, h, p);

                    pixelVecLoc++;
                }
            }

            imageData = imageData.scaledTo(600, 500);
            Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromImageData(imageData).createImage();
            //Image image = new GVImageProcessingJNIWrapper().GetBMPFromGTX();
            e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @gpasch I don't understand your comment

Comment: Could you provide more information on that `Pixel` class and how your pixels are generated? Is there a possibility that `pixel.Blue` has a value greater than `0xff`, causing the upper bits to leak into the green channel?

Comment: @Alden. Good point. I've updated now. Could issue be byte to Int conversion on Java side

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy are other colors correct? For example did you tried to use your code with a red image? Is red correctly displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!  It was the conversion from byte to int.

I needed to use this:

```
Byte.toUnsignedInt
```